# IIS6 windows server 2003 - won't run some .exe program while others it will

Tags: windows, vbscript, asp-classic, server, iis-6

So as i stated in the header. im working on some old instrument. Im using windows server 2003 and classic asp to make something (dont ask why...).

Im using

```
   set objectShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
   objectShell.Run "cmd /c" & command,1,true
```

when command will be the .exe file and maybe some parameters.
Now this works for several .exe program that i need that dont have GUI.
i have 1 .exe that needs GUI and i can't see the server opening it when i'm running this code and i dont get any kind of error.

- When i run this command in CMD without the asp file its working (gui is opened and closed without any need for interaction. it just must open it for some reason).
- When i try to run notepad.exe from server asp it does pop the GUI.

both of these cases make me kind of confused on what to look for and i cant find anything for quite some time.

and also important

- I run the windows server 2003 on a VMware on my computer and enabled WWW service so when i try to web at my computer i can see the response of the server.

  any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Server 2003 is end of life. It no longer gets any updates... not even critical security patches. It's irresponsible and dangerous to continue using it. Upgrading this server is job #1.

Comment: did you set read/execute permission for your EXE file? user which are running your web application must have read/execute permission for your EXE file.